# WPF IShellItemImageFactory GetImage empty

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

I have a WPF application that needs to display icon thumbnails.
I'm using IShellItemImageFactory interface, below is the code:

```
    private static IntPtr GetHBitmap(string fileName, int width, int height, SIIGBF options) {
        IShellItem nativeShellItem;
        Guid shellItem2Guid = new Guid(IShellItem2Guid);
        int retCode = SHCreateItemFromParsingName(fileName, IntPtr.Zero, ref shellItem2Guid, out nativeShellItem);

        if (retCode != 0) {
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
            //throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(retCode);

        NativeSize nativeSize = new NativeSize();
        nativeSize.Width = width;
        nativeSize.Height = height;

        IntPtr hBitmap;
        HResult hr = ((IShellItemImageFactory)nativeShellItem).GetImage(nativeSize, options, out hBitmap);

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nativeShellItem);

        if (hr == HResult.Ok) return hBitmap;

        return IntPtr.Zero;
        //throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR((int)hr);
    }
```

Icon is fetched using the following code:

```
 IntPtr hBitmap = GetHBitmap(fullPath, 24, 24, 
                ShellUtilities.SIIGBF.SIIGBF_INCACHEONLY | ShellUtilities.SIIGBF.SIIGBF_BIGGERSIZEOK);
```

Problem is that some images are big and thumbnail is not cached and function should return null in this case as I'm requesting INCACHEONLY.

I tried to implement this in C++ and function returns NULL, which is OK as image is not cached.
But in C# method returns an empty image in this case, so nut sure what's the problem.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I'm hope wrapper should do its work, I'm just wondering why does this happen? Are somehow arguments changed when passed to native method?